"User location is not supported for the API use without a billing account linked."
Hello GitHub community,
Executing the Gemini API code snippet causes an error in my Google Colab repository:
code
** "User location is not supported for the API use without a billing account linked."**
Can anyone help?
Run Gemini-pro API request in Python

Sounds like they have restrictions on the API use based on "user location", i.e. the location of the system you are making this request from, resp. its IP address.

https://www.reddit.com/r/ChatGPT/comments/1cryoi7/comment/l41cb0l/: "So, you can use aitsudio in the EU and UK, however if you want to use the API in a frontend, for example, you need to have a billing address (which is weird and a little suspicious - I need to keep an eye on this and make sure they don't charge)"

I post in case it could be helpful for others who landed here like me.
I had the same error when testing Google AI Studio and Gemini API but on my local environment.
Because I'm  based in Germany, I found out that in European countries the unpaid tier of Gemini API is not available (list here).
I didn't want to attach a billing account so I found as workaround to change region via VPN (e.g. switched to Turkey).

Currently, Gemini AI is only available in a select set of regions, here's the list (they update it regularly) https://ai.google.dev/gemini-api/docs/available-regions
However, for some regions, it's required for you to have some billing info attached to your google account for it to work, e.g. the United Kingdom

You will need to go to Google Cloud Console https://console.cloud.google.com/products

select billing, and attach a billing account

I already have my billing account linked and Spain shows up in the available regions. I don't get it...

Ok now it seems to be another problem:                                                                                                     com.google.ai.client.generativeai.type.ServerException: You do not have permission to access tuned model tunedModels/some-tuned-model

@Barrufet lo has solucionado ? Yo tambien en España y Gemini en teoria es gratuito....

Yep ya lo he solucionado, ambos problemas: El del billing account se solucionó al rato después de linkearlo. El del tuned model no puedes acceder con una API key. Tienes que hacerlo mediante oAuth credentials (Yo lo hice en python con un server, en android creo que no puedo)

did my answer help at all?

You need to attach the billing account to the API key in https://aistudio.google.com/app/apikey
